# How can I use Vue 3.x in Shopify theme editor?

Tags: vue.js, shopify, shopify-template

From this Shopify article [Integration with the theme editor](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections/develop-theme-sections-integration-with-theme-editor), it said that:

> When merchants customize sections, the HTML of those sections is dynamically added, removed, or re-rendered directly onto the existing DOM without reloading the entire page.
>
> JavaScript that runs when the page loads will not run again when a section is re-rendered or added to the page. This poses a problem for any custom scripts that would need to be re-run.

I am trying to use Vue 3.x in Shopify theme sections. When a section setting is changed, the section variable is changed (like {{ section.settings.button_color }}. However, the js is not run again, how can I load this updated section value into Vue app?